# Что лучше использовать: couchdb или mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, база-данных

Интересует мнение опытных людей, что лучше использовать? Желательно с аргументами :)

Comment: вот [здесь](http://www.slideshare.net/gabriele.lana/couchdb-vs-mongodb-2982288) читаете и делаете выводы